# Max function repeat value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i am using below query to pick User highest qualification but i get repeated values. because user have more than one qualifications.

```
SELECT     hrQualifications.Qualification,hrUserQualifications.HRUserID,MAX(hrQualifications.QualificationLevel) as Qlevel
FROM         hrQualifications RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  hrUserQualifications ON hrQualifications.QualificationID = hrUserQualifications.QualificationID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  hrUserApplyforPositions ON hrUserQualifications.HRUserID = hrUserApplyforPositions.HRUserID
WHERE     (hrUserApplyforPositions.HrPositionID = 1)
group by hrQualifications.Qualification,hrUserQualifications.HRUserID
```

output which i got

```
Qualification    UserID      QualificationLevel
B.Sc.(Hons)        12        16
    F.Sc           12        12
B.Sc.(Hons)        18        16
```

require output. i want highest qualification of user.

```
Qualification    UserID      QualificationLevel
B.Sc.(Hons)        12            16   
B.Sc.(Hons)        18            16
```

Comment: Going to need some more information, likely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do what you want is to use `row_number()`.  This adds a sequential number to rows, starting over again within a partition and ordered by another field.

For your query:

```
with t as (
      SELECT q.Qualification, uq.HRUserID, q.QualificationLevel as Qlevel,
             row_number() over (partition by uq.HRUserID
                                order by q.QualificationLevel desc
                               ) seqnum
      FROM hrQualifications q RIGHT OUTER JOIN
           hrUserQualifications uq
           ON q.QualificationID = uq.QualificationID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
           hrUserApplyforPositions uap
           ON uq.HRUserID = uap.HRUserID
      WHERE uap.HrPositionID = 1
    )
select *
from t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that I also added table aliases to make the query more readable.